Sqlalchemy joinedload do not load child if not used
I have this problem, I'm building a backend in fastapi with sqlalchemy and a postgres database.
I created this endpoint, but the joinedload does not return the indicated fields.
@router.get("/drivers")
def getDrivers(db=Depends(get_db), user=Depends(get_current_user)):
    return db.query(DriversModel).options(joinedload(DriversModel.entita)).all()

return this:
[
    {
        "id_entita": 65
    }
]

these are the models

class EntitaModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entita'
    __table_args__ = {  
        "autoload_with": engine,
        "extend_existing": True
    }
    associazione_indirizzo = relationship(
        "AssociazioneIndirizziModel", back_populates="entita")



class DriversModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'drivers'
    __table_args__ = {  
        "autoload_with": engine,
        "extend_existing": True
    }

    entita = relationship("EntitaModel")


by doing so, the joinedload provides only the fields of the drivers table.
What am I doing wrong? it seems that sqlalchemy only loads the data when needed, but shouldn't joinedload load it instantly when the first query is executed?
If i do this instead:
@router.get("/drivers")
def getDrivers(db=Depends(get_db), user=Depends(get_current_user)):
    res = db.query(DriversModel).options(joinedload(DriversModel.entita)).all()
    for r in res:
        print(r.entita)
    return res

return this:
[
    {
        "entita": {...}
        "id_entita": 65
    }
]

It return correctly the drivers witht the field "entita".
The tables are linked correctly with a foreign key in the drivers table which points to the PK of the entity table.

What type is the route supposed to return?  I suspect you'd need to use pydantic if you want to follow relationships like this.

@snakecharmerb  why should I use pydantic? Isn't joinedload's normal behavior to always return all fields?

The question is, what is FastAPI's behaviour when you return SQLAlchemy objects from a route?  I couldn't find a definitive answer (the reference docs pages seem to be down).

@snakecharmerb Good point. I always understood that it returned the exact dict of the model returned by the query
